# How to combine date and time field in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time

I have a date field and a time field that I would like to combine in to a new datetime field.

Using MS SQL-Server

They are currently formatted like:

```
date: 2019-06-25 00:00:00.0000000
time: 0001-01-01 09:09:31.0000000
```

both fields are `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

I would like the end result to be:

```
20190625090931
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What database are you using? #Oracle What are the fields formats?

Comment: SQL Server - currently both fields are NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: Is it required or to be assumed that `date` will always have a zero component for the time, and `time` always has a "zero" (i.e. `0001-01-01`) component for the date? Manipulating the strings so the result can be converted is simpler than adding "arbitrary" values (i.e. `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2, LEFT('2019-06-25 00:00:00.0000000', 11) + RIGHT('0001-01-01 09:09:31.0000000', 16))` can then be `FORMAT`ted further, or better yet, actually stored in a column).

Comment: Ouch...why nvarchar(max)? There are no characters that require the extended character set and none of them are going to get even close to more than 8,000 characters. Choosing the proper datatype is crucial in developing a good database. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(date AS date), 'yyyyMMdd') + FORMAT(CAST(time AS time), 'hhmmss')
```

should work...

Comment: though this will work, I have to warn about using the format function, it performs horrible. So if your table has a large number of rows this could have a serious impact on performance

Comment: I agree 100% with @Guido but given that the original datatypes are varchar(max) I can assume performance must not be horribly important. ;)

Comment: Sorry, Sean - I just saw the comment that the code is not working, and a -1 in front of the answer, so I thought it was you... let's forget it.

Comment: As the original field types are nvarchar(max) it could be done with the SUBSTRING() function as well, but this is less complicated. And I guess that performance is not so important here as Sean stated... ;-)

Comment: I agree here, storing this in a `nvarchar(max)` really must mean that performance and good database design are not of any importance here

Comment: Thanks! that did what I was wanting!

Comment: @JasonHamrick What you really should want is to fix your database design and fix the column types

Comment: it's not a production database and is only going to exist for a couple of days to update values elsewhere.