# SQL Server: combine date column and time column, insert into datetime column

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, time, casting

I have a database with a date and a time stored separately in datetime columns (not my idea). I need to combine their values to put into another table with a datetime column. As simple as this seems, I just don't seem to be able to do it.

I can get my date value:

```
cast(sampledate as date)   --  returns '2014-11-01'
```

And my date value:

```
cast(CollectionTime as time)   -- returns '06:46:00.0000000'
```

I've tried a few different ways of putting them together that look OK.

For example:

```
concat(cast(sampledate as date) , ' ' , cast(CollectionTime as time))  -- returns '2014-11-05 08:14:00.0000000'
```

But when I try to insert this into a datetime column, or even just cast it as a datetime value, it doesn't work:

```
cast(concat(cast(sampledate as date) , ' ' , cast(CollectionTime as time)) as datetime)
--  I get the error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166135/how-to-combine-date-and-time-field-in-sql) warned me against using the FORMAT function, and I've been to some other sites that tell me what NOT to do, but I just can't seem to do this simple thing. Can anyone help? Thanks.

EDIT: Figured it out. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622384/combining-concatenating-date-and-time-into-a-datetime) solved it for older versions of SQL, but not current versions. However, it works fine if you cast to datetime2(0), not datetime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622384/combining-concatenating-date-and-time-into-a-datetime

Comment: Hassan, thanks, those used to work in SQL2008, but I've tried that, and it doesn't seem to work in 2016. Should have specified that in my question.

Comment: The duplicate link [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b17efdf01f1f88ea2e0ea0e18b07f19) works just fine in current versions of sql server

Comment: You can simply convert two elements to datetime and add them together.  Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68519014/concatenating-date-and-time-in-sql-to-get-datetime-1900-01-01-instead-of-actual/68519068#68519068

Answer (score 1):

As I commented above, here is an example where you can add the two datetimes together.

If either column is NOT `datetime`, simply `convert` that column to a `datetime`

```
Declare @YourTable table (sampledate datetime,CollectionTime datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2019-06-25 00:00:00','09:09:31')


Select *
      ,NewDateTime = sampleDate + CollectionTime
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
sampledate                CollectionTime            NewDateTime
2019-06-25 00:00:00.000   1900-01-01 09:09:31.000   2019-06-25 09:09:31.000
```